# How to escape equal sign in the application.yaml key

Tags: spring-boot, properties, yaml

I have an `application.yaml` file with the map. The one of the keys contains an equal sign at the end which is constantly escaped:

```
my-map : {
    mykey=:'myvalue'
}
```

Options that I have already tried:

```
"mykey="
'mykey='
mykey\=
mykey\\=
"mykey\="
"mykey\\="
'mykey\='
'mykey\\='
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

`['mykey=']:'myvalue'`

Comment: For future reference, the proper way to escape is "[key]". The way described above includes the brackets in the key (at least in Spring Boot with @ConfigurationProperties)